# NSDateFormatter yyyy is invalid in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, nsdateformatter

I use following date format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

In iOS 6 I get the year as 2013 but for iOS 7 it gives 0013. Is there any solution for this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, and precisely what has been mentioned before, but I can't remember what it is for sure.  I'm thinking it's that you didn't specify a locale and the default one in your case is a bit flaky.

Comment: what input are you providing to dateFormatter? It works fine if I use [NSDate date] on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. The mistake is with the date object itself. When saving initially I get the date format as 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss'and convert it to NSDate and save it. When retrieving I get the NSDate but when I print it it prints the year as 0013 where in that case it does not properly identify the prefix it seems. Ideally this should be correct since there is no point saving the year without all 4 digits since 13 comes in every century.

Comment: There is a way to specify the default date to fill in any missing pieces.  I'm thinking `[dateFormatter setDefaultDate:[NSDate date]]` (for the date formatter used to read the MM/dd/yy date) will do it.  (I think the iOS7 change may have been to change the default default date, at least for some locales.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your date string may not be what you're expecting. If the date formatter is expecting a four-digit year, than that is what you need to give it.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"stringFromDate: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

NSString *dateString = @"11/06/13 10:36:11";
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateFromString: %@", date); // year = 0013

dateString = @"11/06/2013 10:36:11";
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateFromString: %@", date); // year = 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should

```
dateFormatter.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

And

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```